# Set up a Ghost blog at /blog on Meteor

Tags: meteor, nginx, ghost-blog

I am not sure if this is possible but there is a way to host a Ghost blog at a subfolder instead of a subdomain https://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/

I have set up everything on that end the way it says and now the only thing that is needed is to exclude `/blog` from the `FlowRouter.notFound` function. is there a way to do that or set up the route to listen to nginx?

// EDIT

Here's the nginx config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}
```

here's ghost config

```
config = {
   // ### Production
   // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment.
   // Configure your URL and mail settings here
   production: {
      url: 'https://www.raiseyourflag.com/blog',
      //everything else
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate issues here.

1. Setting up Ghost to be served a subdirectory through Nginx. [The tutorial you linked to](https://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/) covers exactly that.
2. Integrating the blog with a second site based on Meteor.

It's not clear if you've completed the first step or not, so let's make sure that's taken care of first:

# Make sure your `config.js` for Ghost includes /blog in the `url` key in the *development* section: 'http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog'
 # Start Ghost in in the development enviroment: NODE_ENV=development node index.js
 # Check that something is actually running on port 2368: `sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':2368'`
 # Go here in your browser, you should see your Ghost blog and be able to browse it: http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog

If you have gotten that far, your Ghost blog is working and you are ready to access it through Nginx on port 80. To simplify the problem for this step, move any Meteor code out of the way temporarily so this can be verified.

Your Nginx configuration looks good. Just `reload` Nginx once more for
good measure, and then check this URL in your browser now:

- http://127.0.0.1/blog

Now you should see your Ghost blog again, but now accessed through Nginx and proxied to the other port.

Once you've confirmed that step is working, add put the Meteor frontend code back in place. From the perspective of any frontend code, `/blog` is just like any URL handled by the web server.

If you go to `/blog` and see a NotFound page served by Meteor, that means that the client-side Meteor framework must have loaded from /somewhere/, presumably `/index.html`. In this case, there's a problem with the Nginx configuration. Perhaps there is more to it whant you have posted?

Comment: i've done the first part. My issue is that when I go to `/blog`, FlowRouter takes over and considers it as part of the NotFound group and renders the not found page. If nginx should work regardless of FlowRouter, I can post the nginx config here

Comment: updated question and unfortunatelly not seeing my blog at that url :( and i can't setup a prefixed path since my app needs to live at the root of the domain

Comment: also, since my meteor app and ghost are on two different IP's how do i configure the proxy/which side do i do it on?

Comment: There is no further configuration required regarding IPs. It is normal for Nginx to proxy requests to other services running on 127.0.0.1 which are not accessible from public IP addresses.

Comment: The issue here was with FlowRouter not sending requests to the server. It's an SPA. The request for /blog doesn't even make it to the server.